# Getting value in a dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the below dataframe and I'm trying to get the value **3097** as a int, e.g. storing it in a python variable to manipulate it, multiply it by another int etc.

[image]

I've managed to get the row, but I don't even now if it's a good way to do it and I still can't have the value as a int.

```
data.groupBy("card_bank", "failed").count().filter(data["failed"] == "true").collect()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the first record from the Row object using index 0 and get the value using the index "count"

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
data.groupby("card_bank", "failed").count().filter(col("failed") == "true").collect()[0]["count"]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a `row` from the sequence (wither for loop or map function) and then `row.getInt(2)` according to  https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the value from spark dataframe :-

```
df =data.groupBy("card_bank", "failed").count().filter(data["failed"] == "true").collect()
value = df.select("count").as[int].collect()
```

here, value will be a list.